# IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, verify

We have an Angular application that is using the capacitor-oauth2 Library to get tokens from from our Azure AD and Azure B2C AD.
Wenn I have the Token from B2C I can verify it with following Code in my Program.cs and I can call my Controller Funktion

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("B2C", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = $"https://eisvogel2.b2clogin.com/eisvogel2.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_susi/v2.0/";
        options.Audience = $"6fba7d06-5b7a-41bd-8371-6f1ad6f3176c";
    });
```

But wenn I get a Token from our internal AD which is coming from MS Graph I can do what I want I always get the following Exception:

[image]

for this I'm using the code that the Studio is generating when creating a new Solution with authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
and changed the Config
[image]

I already tried the conclusions from various posts but nothing really help

I know there a lot of similar post and I'm search now for 3 days. It would be nice if someone could nudge me in the right direction.

Remark: I forgot to mention that I built the solution on .NET 6. are there any differences to the predecessors?

Comment: Have you tried giving scopes that you have exposed and granted consent to  like api://<clientId>/<scope name> .See [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1334)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @kavya Saraboju for pointing me again to this post. After some more ding I understood that I have to use the same Scope on server and client side. And it must be the Scope name you can find under "Expose an API" in Azure that looks like this =>

"Scopes": "api://xxxa2967-1111-2222-3333-xxx9c0d72231/tasks.read",

I played around with so many Scopes like openid / starting with http:// just the Name nothing worked.
So for all others: There are hundreds of examples out there with different ideas => just copy your Data from Azure and If you have more than one Application that has to deal with Azure AD, the configuration must be equal.